# Как создать клон объекта?

Tags: c#

Как можно сделать клон объекта на C#? Дело в том, что я работаю над структурой данных "Список", и нужно сделать метод, который будет клонировать список, т.е. создаётся новый список, на основе какого-либо, и с ним можно работать независимо от клонируемого, если я правильно понимаю, если нет, то поясните, что значит клон объекта.

Comment: `MemberwiseClone` не подходит?

Comment: @nick_n_a, смотрел примеры, но не понял, как им пользоваться

Comment: При копировании оператором = создаётся ссылка, затем при изменении обьекта меняется исходный. А после клонирования - исходный обьект не меняется.

Comment: А что должно быть с элементами списка? Они должны тоже склонироваться, или просто лежать в _обоих_ списках?

Answer (score 4):

Клон - копия объекта в памяти. Он отличается от исходного тем, что при изменении клона исходный объект не меняется (в отличие от ссылки), также он занимает дополнительную память. Простейший пример клона - [MemberwiseClone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public  class tx {
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public tx Clone() { return (tx)MemberwiseClone(); }
}

static public void Main() {
    tx z1 = new tx();
    z1.a = 0;
    z1.b = 0;
    tx z2 = z1;
    tx z3 = z1.Clone();
    z2.a = 1;
    z3.a = 3;
    Console.Write("z1.a={0} z1.b={1}", z1.a, z1.b);
    Console.Write("z2.a={0} z1.b={1}", z2.a, z2.b);
    Console.Write("z3.a={0} z1.b={1}", z3.a, z3.b);
}
```

Ну и как вариант снятия "рамок" Microsoft-а:

```
public T Clone<T>(T obj) {
    return (T)typeof(T).GetMethod("MemberwiseClone", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(obj, null);
}
```

`MemberwiseClone` - функция `Object`, которая находится в секции `protected`, поэтому она доступна изнутри класса (в примере для этого я создал ф-цию `Clone`, но, как вариант, её можно вызвать с помощью `Reflection`). А вот если объект содержит ссылки на объекты, то его клонирование усложняется.

Если вы хотите копировать список, то, боюсь, придётся делать иначе (потому что скопируется экземпляр оболочки списка, а ссылка на весь массив будет такой же):

```
List<object> newList = new List<object>( srcList.ToArray() );
Dictionary<object,object> newList = new Dictionary<object,object>( srcList.ToArray() );
```

А если вам нужны копии каждого элемента, то нужно что-то такое (можно переписать с использованием Template):

```
List<object> CloneList(List<object> srcList) {
    object newArray = new object[srcList.Count]; 
    srcList.CopyTo(newArray);
    return new List<object>(newArray);
}
```

Последняя функция равносильна по действию `Array.Copy`. `Array.Copy` нужна, если просто нужен клон массива.

Comment: а может ли метод принимать в качестве параметра объект? (объект "Список")

Comment: Для списка вы можете использовать `List.CopyTo`, это упростит задачу. Я не пробовал MemberwiseClone на списке. Ещё вариант - `Array.Copy`

Comment: MemberwiseClone копирует значения и ссылки, поэтому обвёртки List и Dictionary прийдётся копировать через CopyTo.

Answer (score 1):

Например как метод в базовом классе:

```
public virtual BaseObject ShallowCopy()
{
    return (BaseObject)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное всем)